# How to should I configure this network with multiple static IP addresses for security and efficiency?

Tags: router, ip, access-point

I am setting up a network in a business. They have five static IP addresses and prefer to keep their point of sale computers on a separate static IP addresses, separate from their customer Wi-Fi and IP camera system IP addresses. I have attached a diagram of the current setup, and I also put the make and model numbers of the hardware. The only thing not on here is the hardware I just ordered to set up public the Wi-Fi hotspots: three Ubiquiti Networks Enterprise AP Unifi (UAP) and TP-LINK TL-R470T Router. 
[image: Network Map]

Please advise the best way to set this up for the long run.

Note: the Point of sale is on *both* the Front-desk computers, downstairs office computers, and the iPads.

The goal is to give first priority Internet bandwidth to the office and front-desk computers, second priority to the camera system and, third priority to the public Wi-Fi hotspots.

If additional hardware is needed, please let me know as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of your goals should be to logically separate the POS systems, cameras, and other computers.  Create VLANs for each class of device, so that you can filter traffic to each (for example, you don't want your POS systems to be able to talk to cameras, other PCs, public wifi, or the Internet).  If your switches do not support VLANs, that would be the first thing I would upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why they would want the PoS systems to have public addresses since that would be the highest priority to protect. Usually those addresses are reserved for devices which need to be accessed from the public Internet.

It sounds like you need to configure VLANs and QoS.

You can trunk a single VLAN for the PoS systems to the switches where the PoS systems are, and not to the other switches.

You can mark the various packets on the switches and queue on the router WAN interface based on your priorities. You can't really control incoming traffic, and that is usually a lot more than the outgoing traffic. Marking on the router will drive up CPU utilization, and it is always best to mark it as close to the source as possible

Comment: Hi Ron, ty for your answer and edits. The POS on static IPs prevents anyone off site from accessing and tampering with the system. 
So I should set up a VLAN on the router since the POS is being accessed at multiple different loc. (upstairs/Front desk/office) or should i put a router in front of the main router for this purpose?

Comment: If the main switch is a layer-3 switch, you should put the VLANs on it, otherwise you put the VLANs on the router (router-on-a stick). Also, I wouldn't recommend that you use routers for the Wi-Fi. You can get WAPs less expensively. WAPs are designed to be able to be placed where they are needed, and moved as needed, when conditions on the airwaves change, and usually are powered with PoE. You are getting routers to do the job of a bridge; you should use the correct tool for the job.